# Python: Sort a list into multiple lists or dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of strings, here's an example:

```
wallList = ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1', 'wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1',
             'wall_vwh_l0','wall_vwh_l1', 'wall_vwh_broken_l0', 
             'wall_vwh_broken_l1', 'wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1', 
             'wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']
```

And I'd like to group them together by wall type, and state (default / broken):

```
[['wall_l0', 'wall_l1'],['wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1']]

[['wall_vwh_l0', 'wall_vwh_l1'],['wall_vwh_broken_l0', 'wall_vwh_broken_l1']] 

[['wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1'],['wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']]
```

Anyone know how best to do this, or know of a python recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, first we need to break it up by wall type so we can do this.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> wallList = ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1', 'wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1',
         'wall_vwh_l0','wall_vwh_l1', 'wall_vwh_broken_l0', 
         'wall_vwh_broken_l1', 'wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1', 
         'wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']
>>> list(groupby(sorted(wallList), lambda wall: wall.replace('_broken', '')[:-3]))
[('wall', <itertools._grouper object at 0x1004edc50>), ('wall_vpi', <itertools._grouper object at 0x1004edb90>), ('wall_vwh', <itertools._grouper object at 0x1004eda90>)]
```

great now that we have the types lets separate by those that are broken.

this is what everything looks like together.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> wallList = ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1', 'wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1',
         'wall_vwh_l0','wall_vwh_l1', 'wall_vwh_broken_l0', 
         'wall_vwh_broken_l1', 'wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1', 
         'wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']

>>> values = [[list(v) for k, v in groupby(values, lambda value: '_broken_' in value)] 
...             for key, values in groupby(sorted(wallList), lambda wall: wall.replace('_broken', '')[:-3])]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(values)
[[['wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1'], ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1']],
 [['wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1'],
  ['wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1']],
 [['wall_vwh_broken_l0', 'wall_vwh_broken_l1'],
  ['wall_vwh_l0', 'wall_vwh_l1']]]
```

there are surely other ways, but this seems to be concise.

Here is another way:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> values = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
>>> for wall in wallList:
...     if 'broken' in wall:
...         values[wall[:-3].replace('_broken', '')]['broken'].append(wall)
...     else:
...         values[wall[:-3]]['default'].append(wall)
... 
>>> values.items()
[('wall', defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'default': ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1'], 'broken': ['wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1']})), ('wall_vpi', defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'default': ['wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1'], 'broken': ['wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']})), ('wall_vwh', defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'default': ['wall_vwh_l0', 'wall_vwh_l1'], 'broken': ['wall_vwh_broken_l0', 'wall_vwh_broken_l1']}))]
>>>
```

This second method should be faster since we are only iterating once, dictionary look ups are constant, and we can access any set of walls by name as well as state ...

```
>>> values['wall']['default']
['wall_l0', 'wall_l1']
>>> values['wall_vpi']['default']
['wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1']
>>> values['wall_vpi']['broken']
['wall_vpi_broken_l0', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1']
>>>
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot it also needs to be organized by state. This is in fact the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little one-liner to do it:

```
import itertools, re
results = [list(v) for (k, v) in itertools.groupby(sorted(wallList),
        lambda x: re.sub(r'\d+', '0', x))]
```

This doesn't preserve the order, but otherwise it gets you the same output you wanted.

It works by looking at a version with all numbers converted to '0' and grouping duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: apparently my answer is only partially correct because I forgot to organize by "state". The correct answer is from @samy.vilar.

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(wallList), lambda r: r[:-1])]
[['wall_broken_l0', 'wall_broken_l1'], ['wall_l0', 'wall_l1'], ['wall_vpi_broken_l0
', 'wall_vpi_broken_l1'], ['wall_vpi_l0', 'wall_vpi_l1'], ['wall_vwh_broken_l0', 'w
all_vwh_broken_l1'], ['wall_vwh_l0', 'wall_vwh_l1']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Split on _: `string.split('_')`.  If you get 2 fields back, you have the degenerate case.  If you get 3, group by the middle field of 3.  A dictionary of lists would probably help, or better a collections.defaultdict(list).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.